# Enter values in multidimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

*I am trying to create a single multidimensional array from 2 arrays* **dynamically** by looping both arrays.

Code

```
<?php
$days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"];
$rates = [40,60,80];
$profit = [];

foreach($days as $day => $value){
    foreach($rates as $rate){
    $netprofit = $rate* 20;
     $profit[$value] = [$rate=> $netprofit];
    }


}
print_r($profit);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => Array
        (
            [80] => 1600
        )

    [Tuesday] => Array
        (
            [80] => 1600
        )

    [Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [80] => 1600
        )

)
```

Expected Result

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => Array
        (
            [40] => 800
            [60] => 1200
            [80] => 1600
        )

    [Tuesday] => Array
        (
            [40] => 800
            [60] => 1200
            [80] => 1600
        )

    [Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [40] => 800
            [60] => 1200
            [80] => 1600
        )

)
```

I want to loop the array $days and use it as a key for first dimension of the new array $profit. 
Secondly i want to assign the values of $rates array as the key to the second dimension and assign a value.
I have tried this approach but not found the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest your profits:

```php
foreach($days as $day){
    $profit[$day] = [];
    foreach($rates as $rate) {
        $netprofit = $rate * 20;
        $profit[$day][$rate] = $netprofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the expected result from both answers, just trying to figure out the difference between the two answers. Thanks

Comment: The difference is that my answer doesn't use separate variable to store particular day's data and Hardood uses separate variable. I also cleaned your code a little, because you had your `foreach` loop a bit wrong. You don't use `$day` variable anywhere in your example and you named the day `$value`, while your `$day` is an index of a day: 0, 1, etc.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation, what if i wanted to use the days data in the second foreach loop?

Comment: You can do it, my answer does it actually. See how I'm using `$day` in the nested `foreach`.

Comment: I need some more help with this array. i have posted a new question. Could you please see if you can help? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503533/php-array-to-line-chart-in-chartjs]

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"];
    $rates = [40,60,80];
    $profit = [];

    foreach($days as $day => $value){
      $x = array();
    foreach($rates as $rate){
      $x[$rate] =  $rate* 20;

    }
    $profit[$value] = $x;

    }
    print_r($profit);
```

Comment: I get the expected result. thanks. I also get the expected result from @RoboRobok answer. If i take this approach, i can use the $value of the first array in the second foreach loop?