# Php Array to line chart in ChartJs

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, charts, chart.js

```
        $days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"];
        $rates = [40,60,80];
        $profit = [];

        foreach($days as $day => $value){
            foreach($rates as $rate){
                $netprofit = $rate* 20;
                $profit[$value] = [$rate=> $netprofit];
            }

        }
```

```
        $usersChart = new UserChart;
        $usersChart->labels($days);
        foreach($profit as $key => $value){
            $data = array();
            foreach ($value as $values){
                $data[] = $values;
            }


            $usersChart->dataset($key, 'line', collect($data));
        }
```

[image: Chart generated by the above code.]
I want to show this array into Chartjs Line Graph. I want the x axis to be the 40,60,80. Y axis to be 800, 1200, 1600. The Dataset or Lines should be Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday.
Right now i get Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday as x axis and Line. 600,800 etc are on y axis.

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => Array
        (
            [40] => 800
            [60] => 1200
            [80] => 1600
        )

    [Tuesday] => Array
        (
            [40] => 800
            [60] => 1200
            [80] => 1600
        )

    [Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [40] => 800
            [60] => 1200
            [80] => 1600
        )

)
```

Comment: please provide more code, to know what you have achieved already

Comment: this is an example with only html and javascript, if it help you let me post it as an answer. https://jsfiddle.net/3oa1ukv7/3/

Comment: @yoss thanks for your reply. I see you have structured it nicely by hardcoding the values. I have an array $profit. i want to dynamically create the chart, by looping through my array. I will edit my question with more code to help you. Please see above.

Comment: @yoss, what you have done is what i want exactly. But i need to loop my array to get this result rather than hardcoding the values. Also i am using Laravel Charts, which is a php implementation of Chartjs and other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

keep your array as it is and convert it to JSON object and then echo it inside Javascript, javascript have to be inside php file to run, not in external javascript file.

notice that there is PHP code in this example and i have put `<?php echo $json; ?>` inside the javascript code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>body{width: 800px;}</style>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <canvas  id="myChart" width="700px" height="300px"></canvas>
        </div>      
        <?php
            $array = array(600, 800, 1200, 1800);
            $json = json_encode($array);
        ?>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
              // The type of chart we want to create
              type: 'line',

              // The data for our dataset
              data: {
                labels: ["20", "40", "60", "80"],
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: 'Monday',
                    borderColor: "#FF9F40",
                    data: <?php echo $json; ?>,
                  },
                  {
                    label: 'Tuesday',
                    borderColor: "#FF6384",
                    data: [600, 800, 1200, 1800]
                  },
                  {
                    label: 'Wednesday',
                    borderColor: "#219151",
                    data: [600, 800, 1200, 1800]
                  }
                ]
              },

              // Configuration options go here
              options: {}
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. My array is a multidimensional array. it includes the labels: [ ],  label : ' '  and data : [ ]. How do i loop my array to get the values? I need to dynamically assign the 'labels: [ ]', 'label : '' ', and the data: [] .the number of datasets should also be dynamic. Please see my array above.

Comment: you have to make them in separate arrays like what javascript needs them or choose the array item index,  your code doesn't tell too much unfortunalty

Comment: if data in javascript have to be [600, 800, 1200, 1800] you should make an array like this (600, 800, 1200, 1800) and then convert it to json  and then echo it in javascript

Comment: I understand that i have to echo in javascript. I am clear about that. My problem is how to do the for loop for my array and use it on the required places. You saw the array. Now i want to create the dataset using for loop. Not hardcoding each dataset {  }. If my array contains more data for example, Thursday, Friday, i dont want to make each dataset and label manually. If you need anything else to understand the problem please ask . Thanks for your time

Comment: i don't understand why you have to loop in array, you just have to make clean arrays from the beginning. please provide more php code,

Comment: ok. how do i make clean arrays? can you help me with that?`$days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"];
        $rates = [40,60,80];` These arrays would not be hard-coded, These arrays should hold values dynamically from a user. right now i am using static values for easier understanding purpose.

Comment: from where do you get the dynamic values?

Comment: Previously you said to make separate arrays. Could you please tell me how do i make separate arrays from the existing array i have?

Comment: i haven't included the dynamic code. Let me clarify. I have a `$days` array and `$rate` array. I use it to create a `$profit` array. The `$profit` array structure i have shown above. The values of `$days` and `$rate` can change as a result the number of Lines/Datasets i need are not fixed. that is why i need to loop my array. How do i structure and loop my multidimensional array and get the desired Line chart?

Comment: `<?php
            $array = array(600, 800, 1200, 1800);
            $json = json_encode($array);
        ?>` This code in your answer. How do i get the array values (600,800,1200 etc) from my big array?`datasets: [
                  {
                    label: 'Monday',
                    borderColor: "#FF9F40",
                    data: <?php echo $json; ?>,
                  },` Also, i want to do this code inside a loop because the number of datasets  needed is not fixed. Can you help with this?